# Link/Unlink existing account with OAuth2 provider using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

**Scenario**

1. I have already created an account on my website through OAuth2 login.
2. I am logged into this account with the `SecurityContext` populated with my signed in user.
3. **I wish to link this account with another OAuth2 provider.**
4. **I wish to unlink this account from the original OAuth2 provider.**

My security config is:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()

                .requiresChannel()
                .anyRequest().requiresSecure()

                .and()
                .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .sameOrigin()
                .and()

                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/register", "/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()

                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/?login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .failureUrl("/?error")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .usernameParameter("emailAddress")
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler())

                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")

                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .loginPage("/?login")
                .failureUrl("/?error")
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler())

                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

And my application properties are:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            clientId: <removed>
            clientSecret: <removed>
          facebook:
            clientId: <removed>
            clientSecret: <removed>
        provider:
          facebook:
            userInfoUri: https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,email,first_name
```

**What have I tried**

My first thought was to add another social login button to the to authenticated users screen (note: this is the same as the login button). This correctly redirects them to the OAuth2 provider, they log in, then they're redirected back to the application. The issue is because this goes through the normal filter process for "OAuth2 logging in" it switches the `SecurityContext` to now have the new OAuth2 credentials, losing who was logged in before.

This happens because of the `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter` which extends `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` and in the method `successfulAuthentication` it clears the security context and inserts the new credentials:

```
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        this.logger.debug("Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: " + authResult);
    }

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);
    this.rememberMeServices.loginSuccess(request, response, authResult);
    if (this.eventPublisher != null) {
        this.eventPublisher.publishEvent(new InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent(authResult, this.getClass()));
    }

    this.successHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authResult);
}
```

So I thought hey! Why don't I override the `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter` and then implement my own `successfulAuthentication` which can detect if we already have another user signed in. If we don't, do the normal behaviour. If we do then get that user, pop on them the unique id given to us from the OAuth2 provider and continue the filter chain. *Importantly* not changing the `SecurityContext`.

This turned out to not be very simple as the `OAuth2LoginConfigurer` hardcodes that the `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter` is used and you cannot supply a different one to use:

```
public void init(B http) throws Exception {
    OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = new OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter(this.getClientRegistrationRepository(), this.getAuthorizedClientService(), this.loginProcessingUrl);
    this.setAuthenticationFilter(authenticationFilter);
    ...
}
```

And the `setAuthenticationFilter` method is not public:

```
protected final void setAuthenticationFilter(F authFilter) {
    this.authFilter = authFilter;
}
```

I also would like to unlink the user from their OAuth2 login if they wish and aside from just removing their link in the database to that unique id what else should I do for that?

**Versions being used**

Spring Boot: 2.0.5.RELEASE

Spring Security: 5.0.8.RELEASE

*Thank you in advance. I am happy to provide more information if needed.*

**Note**
I do not believe this has been asked before. After extensive Googling all of the documentation appears to be on logging into the app with OAuth2 login and nothing is around linking that account with another OAuth2 login.

Comment: Hi? Did you find the answer?

Comment: @PavelVarchenko sorry, no. I have moved on from this now.